# trying to implement oauth /token based login using stormpath

Tags: python, authentication, oauth, stormpath

My code :

```
            from stormpath.api_auth import ApiRequestAuthenticator
            import base64

            application = app.stormpath_manager.application
            account = application.accounts[0] # random account
            new_api_key = account.api_keys.create()
            authenticator = ApiRequestAuthenticator(application)
            uri = 'dont_care'
            http_method = 'GET'
            headers = {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(new_api_key.id + ":" + new_api_key.secret)
            }
            result = authenticator.authenticate(headers=headers, http_method=http_method, uri=uri, body={}, scopes=[])
            print result.api_key #<ApiKey href=https://api.stormpath.com/v1/apiKeys/bla_bla>
            print result.account # bla_bla@gmail.com
            print result.token # None
```

What am I missing ?
My code is based on [this part of the documentation.](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/#exchanging-api-keys-for-oauth-20-tokens)

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, I'm the author of this library, so figured I'd hop in here =)

What you'll want to do is something like this. I assume you're trying to do a username/password based login as opposed to an API key login, correct? (EG: You have a front-end client like Angular, or a mobile app making these requests?)

If so, you can accomplish what you want using my example here:

```
from os import environ

from stormpath.api_auth import PasswordGrantAuthenticator
from stormpath.client import Client


STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID = environ['STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID']
STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET = environ['STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET']
STORMPATH_APPLICATION_NAME = environ['STORMPATH_APPLICATION_NAME']
STORMPATH_USER_EMAIL = environ['STORMPATH_USER_EMAIL']
STORMPATH_USER_PASSWORD = environ['STORMPATH_USER_PASSWORD']


client = Client(id=STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID, secret=STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET)
application = client.applications.query(name=STORMPATH_APPLICATION_NAME)[0]


authenticator = PasswordGrantAuthenticator(app=application)
result = authenticator.authenticate(STORMPATH_USER_EMAIL, STORMPATH_USER_PASSWORD)

if result:
    print('Access Token: {}'.format(result.access_token))
    print('Refresh Token: {}'.format(result.refresh_token))
else:
    print('Invalid credentials supplied.')
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response!. I actually want to implement a token based login vs user password. I actually succeed doing that, but now i'm struggling with high response time (800ms). will write that in a different question.

Comment: please review and tell me if you find any errors in my answer

Comment: Your solution looks good. You could also use the specific `OAuthClientCredentialsRequestAuthenticator` to be a bit more efficient =D @WebQube

Comment: Hey, I'm able to obtain the access and refresh tokens, but when I send them to my api via the authorization header, I'm still redirected to the login page on protected endpoints. I feel like just throwing the header at it isn't doing it right, but I'm a noob when it comes to auth stuff. anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I actually used `ApiRequestAuthenticator` to accomplish that

```
def get_api_key(self, app, user_data):

    self.init_authenticator()

    email = user_data['email']
    if not hasattr(self, 'cloud_directory'):
        self.cloud_directory = app.stormpath_helper.get_cloud_directory(APP_NAME + '-' +  env)

    if self.accounts.get(email) is None:
        account = self.cloud_directory.accounts.search({'email': email})
        if account is None:
            raise Exception('failed to find account')

        self.accounts[email] = account[0]

    if self.api_keys.get(email) is None:
        api_key = self.accounts[email].api_keys.create()
        self.api_keys[email] = api_key

    return self.api_keys[email]


# init authenticator to stormpath api to validate access tokens
def init_authenticator(self):
    if not hasattr(self, 'application'):
        self.application = self.app.stormpath_manager.application

    if not hasattr(self, 'authenticator'):
        self.authenticator = ApiRequestAuthenticator(self.application)


def get_client_access_token(self, app, user_data):
    api_key = self.get_api_key(app, user_data)

    uri = 'bla_dont_care.com?grant_type=client_credentials'
    http_method = 'GET'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(api_key.id + ":" + api_key.secret)
    }
    result = self.authenticator.authenticate(headers=headers, http_method=http_method, uri=uri, body={}, scopes=[])
    if result:
        client_token = result.token.token
    else:
        raise Exception('Invalid or not authenticated request.')
```

and for login I use :

```
def is_token_valid(request, authenticator):
    uri = 'bla_dont_care.com'
    # headers = {
    #     'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS5zdG9ybXBhdGguY29tL3YxL2FwcGxpY2F0aW9ucy9WSmlYRFdUV25ZZE5nckZlOUJvSTMiLCJpYXQiOjE0NjM5ODYxNTAsInN1YiI6IjVHWk03REpWNTFRSkhDWk41WENQMDEwRjQiLCJleHAiOjE0NjM5ODk3NTAsInNjb3BlIjpudWxsfQ.MTxQ2AzhlCkOtws4cnwLdrUhLEUGHpMOIATbSX9AeGw'
    # }
    result = authenticator.authenticate(headers=request.headers, http_method='GET', uri=uri, body={}, scopes=[])

    if result is None:
        return False, None

    is_valid = result.account is not None
    return is_valid, result.account
```